# jQuery resizable: don't allow contained div to be out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

jQuery resizable example shows [here](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area) how a div can be resized within the limits of a container.

I need to achieve the opposite effect: the resizable div is the container, and when it's resized it cannot leave the contained div out of bounds, either fully or partially.

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/dzSRR/24/) you can resize the container and leave the contained div outside. My objective is to stop the resize when container's border touches the contained div.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="out-div">
    <div id="in-div"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$("#out-div").resizable();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the inner container to resize proportionally to the outer container?

Comment: Would there be any reason you are not able use maxWidth and maxHeight? http://jsfiddle.net/dzSRR/26/

Comment: That's similar to what I came up with, only I put `min-height` and `min-width` in the CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/dzSRR/27/

Comment: @BrianBennett min-height and min-width shouldn't be static in the CSS

Comment: @ps0604 Not to get into a long discussion here, by why not? It's a valid use of the attributes according to the standards.

Comment: @BrianBennett I agree that your example is valid, the answers below handle more generic use cases.

Comment: @ps0604 Gotcha...makes sense. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a bigger issue. I also realize that you may not want to set restrictions in CSS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzSRR/32/)

I made the in-div draggable just to show that it can be done dynamically. I also changed a bit of the CSS styling.

```
var inPosition = $("#in-div").position();
var top = inPosition.top;
var left = inPosition.left;
var inWidth = $("#in-div").width();
var inHeight = $("#in-div").height();


$("#in-div").draggable({
    containment: "#out-div",
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(){
        inPosition = $("#in-div").position();
        top = inPosition.top;
        left = inPosition.left;
        inWidth = $("#in-div").width();
        inHeight = $("#in-div").height();
    }
});
$("#out-div").resizable({
    resize: function(){
        $("#out-div").css("min-width", (left + inWidth));
        $("#out-div").css("min-height", (top + inHeight));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dzSRR/31/

You need to take into consideration the element position inside a container and its dimensions. In your case its margins but you could also use jquery's **Position().left** and **Postion().top**

```
$("#out-div").resizable();
var yourpadding = 10;
var height = parseInt($('#in-div').css('margin-top')) + $('#in-div').height() + yourpadding;
var width = parseInt($('#in-div').css('margin-left')) + $('#in-div').width() + yourpadding;

$("#out-div").resizable("option",{ minWidth: width, minHeight: height});
```

Comment: your answer also works however Mark was the first to post the answer